# Process Name is Disabled on VS 2010 Debug / Attach to process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to attach VS 2010 debugger to a process (processX), however the process i want to debug is started from another process (processY). So in the process list window processX is disabled. I've started processX manually and tried to attach again. In the process list window processX is not disabled anymore.

Since I **have to** start processY and let it to start processX, is there any way to attach processX?

Comment: Processes in this list are disabled if they already have a debugger attached.

Comment: So you think processY is attached or attaches a debugger to processX, but how i walkaround this? (Im not able to modify processY)